# how to make Correctly a javascript if exist (folder) command?

Tags: javascript

I have been trying for some time to design a script.

In this script I will look for commands with an if query whether a folder exists.

I do this by using a variable make so shall he find the path using the variable.

So as follows "backgrounds /" + variable;

heres my script:

```
$.get( "backgrounds/" + mapname )
    .done(function() { 
      var eld = mapname ;
    }).fail(function() { 
      var eld = "default";
    })
```

thanks ahead...

Comment: Did you try it? what was the result?

Comment: Where is the question here?

Answer (score 0):

```
var folderExists = function(callback) {
  var eld = "default";
  $.get( "backgrounds/" + mapname )
  .done(function() { 
    eld = mapname;
    callback(eld);
  }).fail(function() { 
    callback(eld);
  });    
}

folderExists(function(folderName) {
  if (folderName === "default") {
    alert('Folder doesnt exist apparently...')
  }
}
```

Not that I would ever check the existence of a folder like this, but I might be missing some things.

Comment: so i will that the script are look in a subfolder for the existence of a folder with the name of the variable "mapname" -- when you understand? :S

Comment: @ProJaCore This is pure gibberish, you need to learn to ask proper questions in English before continuing your use of SO.

Comment: srry @PrestonS i dont have attentive in the english leeon :/

Comment: @ProJaCore Perhaps write your question in your native language and use a translator such as [Google](http://translate.google.com/) to convert it to English so we may better understand you.

Comment: yeah but i hate it how google mix the phrases hahahahha

Comment: I think google translate, at this moment, will do better than what we are reading. Try it and update your comments and question.

Comment: Not trying to hurt your feelings, man, but `so i will that the script are look in a subfolder for the existence of a folder with the name of the variable "mapname" -- when you understand? :S` is utterly un-understandable.

Comment: hahahha oh man my bad english with complicated things... yeah ununderstandable :& oke..wait

Comment: @dc2 now its fully translated -- i have luck that i write it in german because its a very near language to english -