# How to write RIGHT a javascript if foler exist command

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello stackoverflow users

I have been trying for some time to design a script.

In this script I will look for commands with an if query whether a folder exists.

I do this by using a variable make so shall he find the path using the variable.

So as follows `"backgrounds /" + variable;`

Here's my script:

```
var mapname = "dolls";

$.get( "backgrounds/" + mapname )
    .done(function() { 
      var eld = mapname ;
    }).fail(function() { 
      var eld = "default";
    })
```

I'm using JQuery version 1.3.2.

I get the following error in the JS Console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<XMLHttpRequest> has no method 'done'
```

does anyone know how I write this code right?
thanks ahead...

Comment: Does this code work as you expect?

Comment: no ...  it doesnt or i am too stupid

Comment: If it doesn't work as expected - then it's not written right. Does it answer your only question?

Comment: If the code you've written doesn't work, try posting the exact error you're getting so we can help you further.

Comment: Haven't you ask [absolutely the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318620/how-to-make-correctly-a-javascript-if-exist-folder-command) less than an hour ago?

Comment: Your `var eld` is only defined in the scope of the done and fail callback.  Maybe define it before your get request.

Comment: Asking the same question again and again won't help. Try break the problem into smaller pieces and solve each one separately. If it's hard for you to ask in English, try to find a forum in your native language and get help there.

Comment: thats not my problem- my problem is nobody has a answer thats the smallest format for my bigggg thing -.- and yea i already ask small parts starting from this post ...

Comment: would be best if someone could help me over teamviewer :/. ...

Comment: @Pavlo now for the minus-votes i cant post one more...

Comment: It requires some time to get a good answer (usually more than an hour), but you have to come up with a good question first.

Comment: why everbody dislike omg -.-

Comment: Here's a [working example of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/S5Gga/)

Comment: omg omg omg @PrestonS I LOVEE YOU SOOO  MUCHH THANK YOU YOU MADE MY DAY OMG YOU ARE THE BEST THANKSS *_____*

Comment: why it doesnt work :/ ? http://mdettt.bugs3.com/TTTindex/Crystal_Load/test.html

Comment: @ProJaCore Your version of JQuery is 1.3.2, I used 2.0.2 in my example.  Upgrade to the latest version if you can.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will attempt to do a GET-request to the URL you specified, which doesn't necessarily mean that it is a folder. If you try this on your local machine without a web server and provide a folder name, the browser will look for "index.html" or "index.htm" in that folder. If it finds one, it will succeed, which is not really what you're after..

About actual filebrowsing. Javascript does not allow file browsing for security purposes.

Comment: no its on the webserver so how i can fix the issue or what should I do so it works

Comment: You are running this JavaScript Server-Side?  Are you using Node.js?

Comment: @PrestonS nothing only the jquery.js is linked in ..

Comment: @ProJaCore, Is this script running Server-Side or in a Browser?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery 1.3 ajax GET request would look something like this

```
var mapname = "dolls";
var eld;

jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "backgrounds/" + mapname,
    success: function(response) {
        eld = mapname;
    },
    error: function(msg) {
        eld = "default";
    }
});
```

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S5Gga/1/)